# how to overwrap console output in linux

Tags: c, linux

When I installing program using apt-get in linux, I saw some kind of great animation on console. installation progress message is changed dynamically not rising up its history. I want to use this method on my program. how to program that?

Comment: `apt-get` is an open-source program, so you can learn by studying the code of `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1):

You use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes). They work in all POSIXy systems, and on old Unix systems, too. Basically everywhere except in Windows, although old Windows did have ANSI.SYS for exactly this, and based on some quick googling it might be supported in new Windows 10 (v1511) and later.

For example:

```
printf("\r\033[2KYour string");
fflush(stdout);
```

Above, `\r` moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line. `\033[` are the two characters the Wikipedia article calls *CSI* (`\033` being ASCII 27, or ESC; followed by `[`). The *CSI 2 K* command, or `\033[2K`, clears the entire line; the cursor stays where it was (at the beginning of the line). Then you can print your thing, but do not include the `\n` that would move the cursor to the next line.

Because standard output is by default line buffered, you need to `fflush(stdout)` to ensure the data is actually output to standard output.

Many utilities use the colored output, especially `\033[0;31m[\033[1;31mFailed\033[0;31m]\033[0m` for red `[Failed]` and `\033[0;32m[\033[1;32mOk\033[0;32m]\033[0m` for a green `[Ok]`.

Comment: In this case there is no need to use terminal-dependent ESC sequences, overwriting the text with white spaces after a carriage return will do the trick.

Comment: @KeineLust: Kind of, but not really. For example, if you show the name of the current file or path, it's nontrivial to know how many spaces you need to write to erase the previous line without overflowing to the next line. `printf("\r%s\033[K", filename); fflush(stdout);` will do that (`\033[K` clears the rest of the line) without problems, if `filename` is not too long to overflow to the next line. On the other hand, I do often use something like "`\r%7.2f%% complete`", which *should* work in all terminals, because the length is fixed. Similarly if the length can only increase.

Comment: I don' t get you, whats the difference between overflowing and cleaning with `[2K` or with `printf` using the length of the old string as width specifier? Anyway, nice answer.

Comment: @KeineLust: In many cases, the number of *glyphs* (columns) a string produces is very hard to find out. Filenames are a good example: in POSIXy systems, they can contain any ASCII-compatible characters except slash `'/'` and nul `'\0'`, and in Linux, often contain UTF-8 sequences like `€`. So, in practice, you do not know how many spaces you need to print to overwrite/erase the previous string. If you use too many, the cursor will overflow to the next line, leaving the previous string visible. The `\033[2K` always clears the line from cursor to end of line, and is therefore simple and robust.

Comment: What about `setlocale` and `mbstowcs` for UTF8? The problem with ESC sequences is not the terminal itself: _The recognition of escape sequences is timing-dependent, and many network protocols will group characters into packets (leading to improper recognition of escape sequences), or separate them (leading to function key sequences being recognized as escape and individual characters)._

Comment: @KeineLust: That will not work with combining diacriticals. None of the terminal emulators I've used have had any issues with "timing"; they work just fine even over variably-laggy network connections, including over telephone networks with well over decisecond half-RTT times. The implementation is nontrivial, but the same effect appears with e.g. function key sequences on even pseudoterminals, so it's definitely a well known area. In other words, I think your paragraph in italics is completely untrue, bunk, except possibly with some exceptionally poor software.

Comment: _None of the terminal emulators I've used have had any issues with "timing";_ me neither, but for some reason all "serious" source you can find (`top`, `aptitude`, `man` ...) make use of `ncurses` / `termcap` for this reason, I have found a lot of programs using `ncurses` just for clear the screen.

Comment: @KeineLust: No, they use ncurses for ease of use and portability. There are lots (as in number of variants) of old non-ANSI terminals ncurses supports. (Terminfo entries describe also properties outside stuff described by ANSI escape sequences, like tab positions, resolution, special key codes produced, and so on.) In practice, the terminal emulators currently widely used support most ANSI escape codes; they are typically xterm-, vt100-, or vt220-like, with very few differences as to how much of the ANSI escape codes they support; most differences are in the non-ANSI stuff.